# Can somebody explain what the components of \ProvidesPackageRCS are for?

Tags: beamer

I aim to create some .sty files for themes that I need to distribute to colleagues.  I'm using a standard .sty file as a template, and I've noticed that the command

```
\ProvidesPackageRCS $Header: path/filename.sty, v (what might be hex) (date) (time) (a username?) $
```

if nothing else, raises a warning if the file name in the header doesn't match the actual file name.  It appears that I can't compile if the `,v`, hex string, or date is missing.  I can put in my own date, but does it matter what hex-looking string I use?

EDIT:

I presume we all have an example of one that works normally, wherever you installed Beamer, perhaps `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/themes/theme/beamerthemeAnnArbor.sty` on a *nix system.  There, the command reads

```
\ProvidesPackageRCS $Header: /cvsroot/latex-beamer/latex-beamer/themes/theme/beamerthemeAnnArbor.sty,v 1.4 2007/01/28 20:48:30 tantau Exp $
```

and when I copy that file and edit it to say

```
\ProvidesPackageRCS $Header: /cvsroot/latex-beamer/latex-beamer/themes/theme/beamerthemeannarbor.sty,v 1.4 2007/01/28 20:48:30 tantau Exp $
```

it compiles but gives a warning, and with something like

```
\ProvidesPackageRCS $Header: /cvsroot/latex-beamer/latex-beamer/themes/theme/beamerthemeAnnArbor.sty,v 1.4 20:48:30 tantau Exp $
```

it doesn't compile because of a runaway argument.

But since the document compiles if the command is left out entirely, I think I'm going to go that route.  I'm not using version control or distributing this en masse.

Comment: i've looked at the rcs-related packages on ctan, and i haven't found one that provides the command \ProvidesPackageRCS -- an MWE would be welcome here.  (MWE being "minimum *non*working example", here)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

RCS is an old source control system which predated CVS (which predated SVN) If you are using RCS or CVS then that `$Header....$` magic comment causes the dates and version number to be updated automatically every time the file is checked in. Presumably the (non standard) `\ProvidesPackageRCS` is extracting those dates and typesetting them or writing them to the log file like a standard `\ProvidesPackage`.

If you are not using RCS or CVS source control you don't want this at all.

Comment: awesome.  and just like that, it's gone.