# Beamer theme with fading (=gradient to transparent) to background image

Tags: beamer, transparency, themes

I am using Singapore theme and want to use a background texture image for my slides. Is there a way to set the gradient in the title background to go 'from title background color to transparent' instead of 'from title background color to slide background'?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## New Answer

This answer now uses the Singapore theme, (downloaded from [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/theme)) and a proper definition of fading.
The new `beamerthemeSingapore2.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackageRCS $Header: /Users/joseph/Documents/LaTeX/beamer/base/themes/theme/beamerthemeSingapore.sty,v d02a7cf4d8ae 2010/06/17 09:11:41 rivanvx $

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\DeclareOptionBeamer{compress}{\beamer@compresstrue}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\tikzfading[name=fade bottom, top color=transparent!0, bottom color=transparent!100]

\mode<presentation>

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{use=structure,bg=structure.fg!25!bg}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\AtBeginDocument{%

 \newcommand\shading{\tikz\fill[path fading= fade bottom, structure.fg!25!bg] (0cm,0cm) rectangle
 (\paperwidth,1.3cm);}

  \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=}
}

\addtoheadtemplate{\shading\vskip-1.3cm}{}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
 \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{lighthouse.jpg}}


\beamertemplatedotitem

\mode
<all>
```

I made the header slightly larger, such that it contains the frame title.

The main file `mwe.tex`

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}

\usecolortheme[named=Yellow]{structure}

\usetheme{Singapore2}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{The questions}
\begin{frame}{Title}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: new fading in headline to image]

The image is from [wikimedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Grisbl%C3%A4nkan_August_2013.jpg) (Renamed to lighthouse.jpg).

## Old Answer

Sorry, this answer does not use the Singapore theme, but a custom headline (which I actually prefer to the Singapore one).

I have combined answers from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38224/28346) and the `tikz`-manual (20.3 Fadings, page 236f). I think I am not properly setting up the `\shade` rectangle, as there is a small gap on the right side. Better use the `\tikzfading` from above.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\setbeamercolor{secsubsec}{fg=orange,bg=black}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=fade bottom]
  \shade[top color=transparent!0,
  bottom color=transparent!100] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
                                                                                                                                                    

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \leavevmode%                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  \hbox{%                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=8.25ex,dp=3.5ex]{secsubsec}%                                                                                                                                             
    \raggedright
    \hspace*{2em}%                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    {\sffamily\Large\color{orange}\thesection.~\insertsection\hfill\insertsubsection}%                                                                                                                              
    \hspace*{2em}%                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  \end{beamercolorbox}%                                                                                                                                                                                             
  }\vskip-0.5pt%                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  \hbox{%                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    \tikz\fill[path fading= fade bottom, black] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,0.5);                                                                                                                                                 
  }%                                                                                                                                                                                                                
}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%                                                                                                                                                                             
 \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{lighthouse.jpg}}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{The questions}
\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: fading in headline to image]

Comment: Great! Thanks! One comment: the first line in sty-file doesn't seem to be needed. Is it supposed to register the new style? Anyway, I skipped it and it works exactly as I needed.

Comment: Actually I didn't have a clue what the command `\ProvidesPackageRCS` does, but a quick search on Tex.SX solved the case ([link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47496/can-somebody-explain-what-the-components-of-providespackagercs-are-for)). Thanks for raising the question.