# Beamer - How to set frametitle box translucent so that backeground image can be seen blurred

Tags: beamer, transparency, frame-title

everybody. I'm a newbie of beamer. I have encountered a problem as the title depicted. I've tried to search similar questions, but none of those can be applied to frametitle box. For example,  `\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}`, this command works, but the color of letters fades too (see following pic). So, could anybody help me solve this problem? thx a lot.
[image: demo image]

**New Added**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\begin{document}
\title{My title}
\author{author}

\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{background.jpg}}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}

\begin{frame}[plain]  %empty title page
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sorry that I've chosen a not so distinguishing background image

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Would you mind to provide us with a minimum code where we can make experiments?

Comment: Demo code is added. thx.

Answer (score 6):

The solution I've found (credits to [Gradient to transparent (horizontal) for beamer frametitle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229593/1952)) consists in changing `frametitle` definition and fixing there two different opacities, one for title `beamercolorbox` and another for `\insertitle` inside it.

Once you know which `frametitle` template want to use, adapt it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \pgfsetfillopacity{.7}       %<------ fix filling opacity
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,left,wd=\the\@tempdima]{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fteleft\endcsname\fi%
    \strut\pgfsetfillopacity{1}\insertframetitle\strut\par%  <---- text opacity
    {%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
      \fi
    }%
    \vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{My title}
\author{author}

\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{lion.jpg}}

\begin{frame}[plain]  %empty title page
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It works perfectly. I appreciate it very much. I have found that link, too. But unfortunately I still don't know how it works. So, I have to post my question here. Next time I will try to fix by myself  :)